# Removing XML elements in Notepad++ with a regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have some XML like this:

```
<div class='post-outer'>
  <article class='post hentry' id='311698957029370981' itemscope='' itemtype='http://schema.org/BlogPosting'>
    <h1 class='post-title entry-title' itemprop='name headline'>
      Tawakkal Fabrics Midsummer Signature Series Collection 2014-2015
    </h1>
    <div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-311698957029370981' itemprop='description articleBody'>

    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Latest Responsive Under Post Add -->
```

I want to change it to:

```
<div class='post-outer'><!-- Latest Responsive Under Post Add -->
```

removing everything inside the element in Notepad++ with a regular expression. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: That would invalidate your HTML (it's not XML). Wouldn't that be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is not the best tool for this but you can try this if work:

```
(?<=<div class='post-outer'>)[\s\S]*?(?=<!-- Latest Responsive Under Post Add -->)
```

Replace this with empty string `''`